# Unable to login into admin site and change

Tags: admin, magento-community, admin-login

i am a layman. don't know anything much about magento based website. i can not open my website and it is not letting me login to admin page. it says  `/home/himalaya/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php` on line 43

Answer (score 0):

[Check the permissions on your Var folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857237/magento-blank-homepage-and-fatal-error-app-code-core-mage-captcha-block-c)

Also try searching the code string/error when you see it:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php on line 43
```

If it's a common error, others may have posted the same question or answer elsewhere and you can narrow down your search with this info.